# Remove private (keychain) data when iOS app is removed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, keychain

I know it's not possible to intercept any kind of event when an iOS app is uninstalled, but is there a way to bind keychain items to an app such that they will be removed along with the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. However, you can use `NSUserDefaults` to know if it's the first time your app is opened, and erase all keychain data, if it helps.

Comment: That was going to be my followup question. :)